Pytesseract to return text inside bounding box
I am currently trying to do named entity extraction on a set of documents. My plan is:

Do OCR using pytesseract
Extract the text
Apply an LLM to get the entities like patient name, age etc.

One of the example scans look like this: 
The output of pytesseract using: text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config='--psm 12') is this:
HR

Community General Hospital

Patient Account #

Medical Record #

12345

INPATIENT REGISTRATION AND SUMMARY FORM

215043

Patient Name (Last) (Fir) (Middle)

‘Attending Physician Number and Name

Patieat Type

Tae Date

“Adin time

Brown, John

Now, as you can clearly see, the "Patient Name (Last)(First)(Middle)" comes first and the actual name of the patient (Brown, John) comes at the end. How can I make sure the pytesseract returns the text according to the boxes below, i.e. "Patient Name (Last)(First)(Middle)" followed by "Brown, John" and then proceed to "Attending Physician Number and Name"? If tesseract cannot do it, is there a way to get this for any document?
The reason for this requirement is that the LLM can more accurately tell the patient name if it falls right after "Patient Name" rather than later in the output text.

Sorry for putting this an answer even though this is a suggestion. (I can't comment yet due to insufficient reputation).
I think this can be done using openCV along with Pytesseract. Since there are boxes in your provided image, we can identify them using a contour detection in openCV and split the entire image into several parts using those contours.
Then for each sub-image, we can run pytesseract and extract text.
I will try to provide a working code if I can get it to work.

Even a working example would suffice
